# Cannot install php5-mysql in Debian

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I try to do an apt-get, it gives me a dependency on an earlier php5-common than the one I have installed. What do I need to do? Thanks!

php5-common (= 5.6.9+dfsg-0+deb8u1) but 5.6.11+dfsg-1 is to be installed

Comment: Did you try to upgrade from stable (jessie) to testing (stretch) or install something from one or the other? 5.6.9+dfsg-0+deb8u1 is the version of php5-common in stable, 5.6.11+dfsg-1 in testing. The php5-common dependency of php5-mysql is correct in both releases.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I already solved it. Went to the earlier version of php5-common with this command:

sudo apt-get install php5-common= 5.6.9+dfsg-0+deb8u1

Then installed php5-sql, but then PHP stopped working, so I reinstalled the latest version of php5-common and everything looks fine, I am running Joomla without any problems!